# Encrypt Controller Code

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, yii, security

I am using shared hosting and I programmed a web system for a company, but it's now stolen and I noted it on another web site, because hosting root give all my code to another company.

So I guess this problem not just with me, it was happened with all programmers.

Lets make this question as a bit broader to obtain good solutions:

Hosting Section :

1- if administrator  of server not honest and sell the code to another company .

Solution : 
buy my own server , good but for example I have no control o my clients to force thim to 
by servers so we still need to think i on another solution .

Hacking Section :

1- on shared hosting any hacker can hacking all sites on same server if he hacked one weak site in the same shared hosting .

http://hackrepair.com/why-shared-hosting-can-be-bad-for-the-health-of-your-business

2- hacker can download database and full php script .

Solutions on shared hosting :

1- encrypt php files by using programs like zend or sourcecop ..etc  .
2- add php function to check if current domain related to domain that own the script .

So my questions is :

1. How to secure the code ?
2. If I used program like SourceCop, would this encryption  will make the code slow? http://www.sourcecop.com/

Comment: http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/downloads

Comment: If you don't trust your host, get your own server. :)

Comment: Wait? Your hosting company lets you see the code of other accounts on a shared server?

Comment: May I ask who has stolen the source code? If it is an (ex) client, then you should have a contract in place to determine who owns the intellectual property of the system after you have written it.

Comment: @decez I can't force my clients to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would say you're problem is not programming related but system security related. The fact that your clients hosting account is accessible by others is the real problem. You can implement solutions to encrypt your code, but with server access they can still access those files, as well as databases and any other server related technology.

I would strongly suggest fixing the account access first. If the shared access is the result of the type of hosting account, I would try to explain the security issues they have because of that account type and try to get them move to their own account. They can have all sorts of information stolen from them once the site is up and running.

Comment: thank you , in public you can't trust in any root of shared hosting . So my plan is encrypt my code , also what about  some hacker hacking my site and leaked all my code ?! how to protect it  after leaked ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to provide a few more details about your hosting set up - nothing compromising but a few more details would help. Most regular hosting accounts give access to for the account to the account owner. After that they create the ftp accounts, e-mail accounts, etc. So you are saying that it is a shared hosting environment but someone a user or two has access to the whole server?